# How to load data into modal?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to dynamically load data into the body of my modal but cannot seem to get it to work.

```js
function legend(mb) {
    var url = mb;
    var location = document.getElementById("choice2");
    var gwc  = location.options[location.selectedIndex].value;

    if (gwc == 15)
    {
       title = ['<strong>Geomorphology</strong>'];
       var url = 'http://localhost/geoserver/apib/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=25&LAYER=apib:chamapwathi_block_gm&legend_options=fontSize:14';
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the modal code or what you have done on [CodePen](https://codepen.io) or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I am taking reference modal https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have only the javascript tag there, I am adding a basic javascript solution. In my example, content changes on button click, which you would have to do when you get the data from your API call.

I have also added an id attribute to the modal body.

`document.getElementById('left-modal-body').innerHTML = 'Hello';`

[Updated Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLMjdr)